# Remove my name from a Wikipedia article

Tags: wiki, wikipedia, privacy

My full name is mentioned on a (German) Wikipedia article. Do I have the rights to remove it if I prove my identity?

If so, what are the required steps?

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a programming problem nor on topic for any other Stack Exchange site.

Comment: You should ask at https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Fragen_zur_Wikipedia (or even write them an email, https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Kontakt) if you have problems with being mentioned (most people can be proud of it!).

Comment: In simpler cases just remove it yourself from the article and put a comment in why you don't want to see it. It will still be in the revisions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming, at all.

Answer (score 0):

Register on wikipedia, edit the article yourself, flag the article as controversial. Leave a note explaining the edit claiming your right to privacy.

However, this question is completely off topic here, my friend.